# YQL query to retrieve all listed companies symbols in a given stock exchange

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, stocks

I need a YQL (Yahoo Query Language) query. The quesry should give me all the companies symbols listed in a given stock exchange.

Here is a psudocode for what I am looking for:

select * from yahoo.finance.??? where exchange(??) in ("NYSE","OTCEI")

The query should return all IPOs listed in the current stock exchange

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same functionality, did you find out anything?

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quote where (symbol = "ALU" and StockExchange  ="NYSE") OR (symbol = "YHOO" and StockExchange  ="OTCEI")
```